# Реализация метода шифрования DES

Tags: java, шифрование, binary

Здравствуйте! Вообще возникла необходимость написать программу на Java, которая будет шифровать входящие сообщения методом DES, с заданием своего собственного ключа. Теперь самое главное - **ключ и сообщение, которое нужно зашифровать, задается в двоичном виде**, вот с этим у меня и возникли  проблемы.

Сам код:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.DESKeySpec;

import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;


public class Cryptography {

    public static String DES_ENCRYPTION_KEY;
    public static String INPUT;

    private static final String CRYPTOGRAPHY_ALGO_DES = "DES";
    private static Cipher cipher = null;
    private static DESKeySpec keySpec = null;
    private static SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = null;

    public static String encrypt(String inputString, String commonKey)
            throws InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException,
            BadPaddingException {

        String encryptedValue = null;
        SecretKey key = getSecretKey(commonKey);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

        byte[] inputBytes = compare(inputString);

        byte[] outputBytes = cipher.doFinal(inputBytes);
        encryptedValue = new BASE64Encoder().encode(outputBytes);
        return encryptedValue;
    }

    public static String decrypt(String encryptedString, String commonKey)
            throws InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException,
            BadPaddingException, IOException {

        String decryptedValue = "";
// When Base64Encoded strings are passed in URLs, '+' character gets converted to space and so we need to reconvert the space to '+' and since encoded string cannot have space in it so we are completely safe.
        encryptedString = encryptedString.replace(' ', '+');
        SecretKey key = getSecretKey(commonKey);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);

        byte[] recoveredBytes = cipher.doFinal(new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(encryptedString));

        int[] out = new int[recoveredBytes.length];

        String s = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < recoveredBytes.length; i++) {

            out[i] = recoveredBytes[i] & 0xFF;
            s += Integer.toBinaryString(out[i]);

        }

        decryptedValue = new String(s);
        return decryptedValue;
    }

    private static SecretKey getSecretKey(String secretPassword) {

        SecretKey key = null;
        try {
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CRYPTOGRAPHY_ALGO_DES);

            byte[] desKeyData = compare(secretPassword);

            keySpec = new DESKeySpec(desKeyData);

            keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(CRYPTOGRAPHY_ALGO_DES);
            key = keyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error in generating the secret Key");
        }
        return key;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try{

            INPUT = "0000101111010101111101111101101110010000010011011011100111010010";
            DES_ENCRYPTION_KEY = "1111101011001011101100110110111001110010000011100001001110011010";

            String encrypted = Cryptography.encrypt(INPUT, DES_ENCRYPTION_KEY);
            System.out.println("encrypted: " + encrypted);
            String decrypted = Cryptography.decrypt(encrypted, DES_ENCRYPTION_KEY);
            System.out.println("decrypted: " + decrypted);

        }

        catch(Exception e){

        }
    }


    public static byte[] compare(String value) {

        try {

            ArrayList<String> str = new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayList<Byte> inputBytes = new ArrayList<Byte>();

            int countS = 0;
            int countE = 8;
            int i = 0;


            while (true) {

                try {

                    str.add(value.substring(countS, countE));

                    //System.out.println(str.get(i));

                    inputBytes.add((byte) Integer.parseInt(str.get(i), 2));

                    //System.out.println(i + " " + inputBytes.get(i));

                    countS += 8;
                    countE += 8;

                    i++;

                } catch (Exception e2) {

                    countE--;

                    if(countE <= countS){
                        break;
                    }

                }

            }

            byte[] array = new byte[inputBytes.size()];

            for (int j=0; j < array.length; j++)
            {
                array[j] = inputBytes.get(j);
            }
            System.out.println("");
            return array;

    }

        catch (Exception e1){

            e1.printStackTrace();
            return null;

        }

    }

}
```

Как можно понять с названия, метод encrypt шифрует сообщение, а метод decrypt - дешифрует. Метод getSecretKey необходим для инициализации ключа. Теперь самое интересное, метод compare создает из строки массив подстрок, почти каждая из которых размером в 8 двоичных разрядов (*catch (Exception e2)* необходим для того, что бы уменьшить индекс *countE* метода *substring()*, в случае если остаток строки меньше 8 разрядов). Далее они парсятся в 10 форму счисления, и поступают в массив, который потом идет дальше в методы шифрования/дешифрирования. 
**Проблема в том**, что если подстрока начинается с 0, ну например 00110101, то в данном случае первые 2 символа при парсинге будут игнорироваться, и в итоге при дешифрации будет получено совсем не то значение (обрезанное). 
Что бы вы могли посоветовать в данном случае?

P.S. можно было бы просто применить к начальной строке getBytes(), и все было бы нормально, да только в этом случае каждый символ будет интерпретироваться отдельно, и в итоге будет получено здоровенное сообщение, что меня не интересует.

Comment: Я мог бы порекомендовать не париться и задавать данные в HEX, например 0A123456 и так далее. Или вообще конкретными байтами, уж не знаю какие там в JAVA аналоги для unsigned char

Comment: да, но для задачи нужно задавать данные именно в бинарной форме

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите сжать данные перед шифрованием, то по моему лучше просто воспользоваться готовой библиотекой: [этой например](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/) или [вот тут разные библиотеки обсуждают](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918189/fast-compression-in-java).

Зашифруете стрингу, получите бинарный массив в итоге и можно отсылать.